# Add 'memberOf' attribute to ApacheDS

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I am trying to simulate Active Directory's memberOf attribute in Apache Directory.  I have added the following entry for memberOf to my LDIF file:

```
dn: m-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.18060.0.4.3.2.1,ou=attributeTypes,cn=other,ou=schema
m-usage: USER_APPLICATIONS
m-equality: distinguishedNameMatch
objectClass: metaAttributeType
objectClass: metaTop
objectClass: top
m-name: memberOf
m-oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.18060.0.4.3.2.1
m-obsolete: FALSE
m-noUserModification: FALSE
m-syntax: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27
```

When I start ApacheDS the following warning is logged:

```
   WARN  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] entry.ServerStringValue - Cannot normalize the value :Encountered name based id of memberOf which was not found in the OID registry
```

This causes problems later on because my application tries to user the memberOf attribute as a search filter.

Is anything wrong with the way I specified the LDIF entry?

Answer (score 14):

For my integration test cases on top of embedded Apache Directory Server I've added both **memberOf** and **sAMAccountName** attributes defined in Microsoft Active Directory server.

```
#########################################################
# MICROSOFT SCHEMA for sAMAccountName and memberOf
# these two attributes are not defined in Apache Directory Server
#########################################################

dn: cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaSchema
objectclass: top
cn: microsoft

dn: ou=attributetypes, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: attributetypes

dn: m-oid=1.2.840.113556.1.4.221, ou=attributetypes, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaAttributeType
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-oid: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
m-name: sAMAccountName
m-equality: caseIgnoreMatch
m-syntax: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
m-singleValue: TRUE

dn: m-oid=1.2.840.113556.1.4.222, ou=attributetypes, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaAttributeType
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-oid: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.222
m-name: memberOf
m-equality: caseIgnoreMatch
m-syntax: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
m-singleValue: FALSE

dn: ou=objectclasses, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: objectClasses

dn: m-oid=1.2.840.113556.1.5.6, ou=objectclasses, cn=microsoft, ou=schema
objectclass: metaObjectClass
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-oid: 1.2.840.113556.1.5.6
m-name: simulatedMicrosoftSecurityPrincipal
m-supObjectClass: top
m-typeObjectClass: AUXILIARY
m-must: sAMAccountName
m-may: memberOf

#######################################################
# Megacorp employees
#######################################################

dn: cn=EmployeeABC,ou=nl_users,DC=corp,DC=megacorp,DC=COM
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: simulatedMicrosoftSecurityPrincipal
cn: EmployeeABC
sn: EmployeeABC
givenName: EmployeeABC
mail: EmployeeABC@megacorp.com
MEMBEROF: CN=just-users,OU=mc_groups,DC=corp,DC=megacorp,DC=com
MEMBEROF: CN=best-users,OU=mc_groups,DC=corp,DC=megacorp,DC=com
SAMACCOUNTNAME: employeeabc
```

Comment: I imported the structue as LDIF in Apache Directory Studio. But I don't have a type called `simulatedMicrosoftSecurityPrincipal`, which should be there, when I understand your code right. Also inetOrgPerson has no attribute `memberOf`.

Comment: My fault, as a beginner I wasn't aware of the fact that I had to restart the server. Now it works. I have further questions, but I think they're too long for a comment, so I'm going to create a new one.

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954197/add-memberof-as-dn-to-apacheds-ldap-server-without-samaccountname

Answer (score 4):

The ApacheDS team is aware of the desire for the `memberOf` *virtual* attribute.  They mention that it will be part of the [2.1.0 release](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/directory-users/201305.mbox/%3C519A54B1.5070200@gmail.com%3E):

> Le 5/20/13 5:53 PM, Danielsen, Jay a écrit :
>
> > I see from the January 2013 archives that memberOf virtual attribute is not yet supported.
> >     Are there any plans or work-in-progress to support memberOf in an upcoming release ? Morst certainly in 2.1.0.
>
> We are currently busy cleaning the 150 remaining issues before a
>   2.0.0-RC1 release, so I think this is something we can have in the next 6 months.
>
> You can create a JIRA to request such a feature.
>
> Thanks !
>
> --  Regards, Cordialement, Emmanuel Lécharny www.iktek.com

And [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSERVER-1844) is the JIRA request.

Comment: should bump the request

Comment: @codenamezero Yes, of course. There are about 4 years gone, and there is still no `memberOf` attribute in ApacheDS...

Comment: Now 6 years are gone, and there isn't even a version 2 release ;-(

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the schema that contains 'memberOf' into the ApacheDS configuration.