# Get all groups where a user is member of in LDAP

Tags: linux, ldap, apacheds, apache-directory

I'm using ApacheDS as directory server which is used in applications like Gogs (Git server like GitLab). My idea is to create groups like `gogs-users` and restrict the login to those group, so that only users who are member of that group are able to login. I have created a `groupOfNames` for this and a testuser, which is added to the gogs group.

The type of `gogs-users` is `groupOfNames` and it has an  attribute `member` which contains the DN of my user (uid=testuser,ou=Users,DC=example,DC=com). So I'm able to see, who is a member of this group.

But I would like to see all groups where a *user* is a member of. When I open the testuser, I see no attribute that could tell me, that he's a member of `gogs-users`. I remember that the proprietary Active Directory had an attribute called `memberOf` whch was queryable in a filter like `(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=CN=gogs-user,DC=example,DC=com))`. That would be exactly what I need.

How can I get this in a free LDAP implementation? I see no way except defining a custom attribute - Which I had to maintenant per hand. That's not good, I would like to have an automated solution, that keep care of those attribute.

**Things I already tried**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502363/3276634 No changes
- https://morenews.blogspot.de/2010/12/adding-active-directory-properties-to.html No changes, too

Note: I did a complete reset after each scheme import, to make sure, that my tests are not influenced by previous changes.

Comment: (member=uid=testuser,ou=Users,DC=example,DC=com) and a base of: DC=example,DC=com may work.

Comment: @jwilleke This gave me the group, not the members. `member` is a attribute of `groupOfNames`. That's the problem I have: There is only a reference from the group to their member user, but not not in the other way from the user to his groups. In AD the `memberOf` attribute fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here are Queries that will go either way but ONLY work for Microsoft Active Directory:

Resolves [all members](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches) (including nested) Security Groups (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2):

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=gogs-user,DC=example,DC=com)
```

And
All Groups a [User is a member of](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches) including Nested Groups

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))
```

Comment: I'm not on AD and I don't want to be, as I said in the first sentence. I worked in the past with AD and I know this, but I need a similar solution for LDAP on ApacheDS.